# Making 7zip outputting files to a list instead of a 7z archive

Tags: command-line, 7-zip, redirection, archiving, list

I would like to know if this is possible, to make the files a 7zip command line would compress ( "7z a ..." or "7z u ..."), go into a text list instead of an actual archive.
Like a "simulation mode", as robocopy has it with the '/L' switch. And I mean without compressing anything or it would be overkill, just redirecting the files to be compressed, into the screen output or a text file.
Something like for instance this dummy command:

```
 7z u -r TEST.7z -no_archive *.doc -ir!c:\projects\*.*  -xr!cache -screen_redirection
```

(**-no_archive** and **-screen_redirection** switches were invented for example purposes)

Is this possible with either DOS batch or Powershell? (or both) This is for purposes of knowing in advance which files 7zip, with the 'u'/update command, would compress/update across several subfolders but also excluding some subfolders with the -xr! switches.
So in that way I would get a list of new/modified files in the folder compared to the ones in the archive.

Many thanks

Comment: Looking at the options of the 7z command, it won't do what you want and there's no workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You (and us) cannot modify 7Zip, so you need to do it another way.

If I understood right your intent,
this list of files can be generated by the following batch command:

```
dir /b /s c:\projects | find ".doc" | find /v "\cache\"
```

What it does is list recursively all the files in `c:\projects`,
extract all `.doc` files, then discard all files in sub-folder `cache`.

For more information, you may consult the help of each command by entering
`dir /?` or `find /?`.

---

If you are looking to compare the files in the 7Zip archive with those on
the disk, 7Zip is not the tool to use.

You could use
[DAEMON Tools Lite](https://www.daemon-tools.cc/products/dtLite)
(free with ads) to mount the archive as a virtual disk.
You can then compare (but not update) the two folders using any
Windows utility, for example
[robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)
(with the `/L` parameter) to list newer files.

Comment: Hi, I wasn't explicit enough with the "update" argument, sorry for that, but I wanted the generated list to have only the folder files changed compared to the ones in the existent archive. 7zip knows the ones to update (instead of the whole set), and I wanted to use that capability of acknowledging the new/changed files.
I changed the question to better reflect that.

Comment: Are you trying to find which files have changed, compared to the files in the zip archive?

Comment: That's exactly right :-)

Comment: I added a possible method to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc , I'll try that.